# Could not find com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2

Tags: java, android, android-support-library, android-cardview

I have added dependency ' compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2'' and compile SDK version is 27, as well as my target version, is also 27 and my build tool version is 27.0.2 still I am getting this type of error:

> Could not find com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2.
>
> Required by: project :app
>
> Please install the Android Support Repository from the Android SDK Manager.
> Open Android SDK Manager

I have already updated the Android Support Repository.

Please help me out what went to wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the version that you are trying to implement exists. Try using:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.0'
```